# JSON/PHP issue, cannot echo the value but it's present

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a small issue. I have a json file which I fetch data from.

When I print_r() the data, I see the field I want. But trying to call them, only 2 on 3 works, one seems to not be fetch-able.

Here the code, if someone have an idea about what's wrong:

Original JSON :

```
[
{
"ņame": "Xcoin",
"rate": "100.0000",
"status": "online"
}
]
```

The JSON with print_r()

```
Array
(
[ņame] => XCoin
[rate] => 100.0000
[status] => online
)
```

When I fetch individually each fields:

```
echo $coin['name']."<br>";
echo $coin['rate']."<br>";
echo $coin['status']."<br>";
```

The result of the previous code:

```
100.0000
online
```

Like if the name was not there! How's possible? I have others array and name fetch correctly, using same format.

Comment: Look at your array keys: `ņ` !== `n`

Comment: What do you mean sorry? Like comparing $coin['name'] with itself?

Comment: You have a letter ņ (with dot under it). It's not the same as normal n letter

Comment: That's not an `n` in the JSON you're getting, it's [one of these](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%85).

Comment: Oh my thanks.  Please write as answer so I can mark as correct @AlexHowansky

Comment: Wow I just thought my monitor was dirty...

Comment: Ya man same here lol. In fact, rate field is inrfield, so I thout it was the i point XD

Comment: @Sammitch me too! Then, wait, it's dirty right there too, that's weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your array keys: `ņ` !== `n` so you're referencing an array index that doesn't exist.

I.e., that is not an `n` in the JSON you're getting, it's one of [these characters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%85).

(TIL this thing is called a [cedilla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cedilla).)

Answer (score 1):

Look it's other character
**ņ**ame != name

Comment: Sorry my man, it's correct, but @AlexHowansky find it before :P